# Can't turn off Strict Standards warnings in MAMP

Tags: cakephp, mamp, php

I've been trying to set up CakePHP on MAMP. All has gone well, except that it's displaying 'Strict Standards' and 'Deprecated' warnings across all pages.

I believe others may have experienced this, and I've followed http://planetcakephp.org/aggregator/items/142-mamp-php5-cakephp-and-strict-standards to set error reporting as:

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL & ~E_STRICT
```

... which made no difference (this obviously included restarting MAMP, and I've also triple-checked that I'm editing the correct php.ini file, as referenced in phpInfo()).

Looking at the phpInfo report, error_reporting is shown a value of '30719', which I understand is machine value for E_ALL. I'm not sure if that's right or not, given what I set in php.ini. I've also now set

```
display_errors = Off
```

which presumably would stop any errors showing... but again, no difference.

Finally, I've also tried editing htaccess files (e.g. including php_value error_reporting 6143) but this doesn't make any difference either.

I'm sure I'm just doing something quite stupid somewhere - can anyone point out what I've done wrong?

Comment: Did you edit the correct `php-ini`? Note, that PHP usually uses a different one for every SAPI (meaning: cli, apache, fpm, cgi, ...) Did you restart the server?

Comment: Did you check that your userland script (CakePHP) doesn't simply reenable it with `error_reporting(~0);` or alike?

Comment: Thanks @KingCrunch - yes, it's definitely the correct php.ini (as referenced by phpinfo... or am I missing something..?). And yes, restarted server.

Comment: @mario No, there don't seem to be any error_reporting(~0) lines, but will keep searching...

Comment: I said "alike", not "literal".

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?  What version of PHP are you running?

Answer (score 2):

Answering a really old question for people who might be facing this issue -

```
Configure::write('Error', array(
    'handler' => 'ErrorHandler::handleError',
    'level' => E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED &  ~E_STRICT, // This line
    'trace' => true
));
```

in `core.php` inside `/app/Config`